# Split columns into two groups. One with numbers that have decimals and one with only absolute numbers

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

I want to sum this data (for example for the letters A-E). For absolute values, this is easy. However for percentages, I need to take into account the weights. I therefore want to split the columns which have decimal places (percentages), from the ones that do not.

The percentage columns should be allowed to have both absolute numbers and decimals. But decimal places are not allowed in the absolute column.

How should I do this?

```
DT <- structure(list(Letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Percentage = c(0.67, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0), Absolute_number = c(1000, 200, 0, -199, 1), 
    PercentageII = c(65.2, 1.2, 22.8, 4, 0), weights = c(2, 3, 
    3, 1, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

  Letters Percentage Absolute_number PercentageII weights
  <chr>        <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A             0.67            1000         65.2       2
2 B             0.2              200          1.2       3
3 C             0.4                0         22.8       3
4 D             0.2             -199          4         1
5 E             0                  1          0         8
```

Expected output:

```
DT1 <- DT[, c("Letters","Absolute_number", "weights")]
DT2 <- DT[, c("Letters","Percentage", "PercentageII)]
```

Comment: I have added the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Filter` :

```
DT1 <- Filter(function(x) is.character(x) || all(x %% 1 == 0), DT)
DT2 <- Filter(function(x) is.character(x) || any(x %% 1 != 0), DT)

DT1

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Letters Absolute_number weights
#  <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A                  1000       2
#2 B                   200       3
#3 C                     0       3
#4 D                  -199       1
#5 E                     1       8

DT2
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Letters Percentage PercentageII
#  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 A             0.67         65.2
#2 B             0.2           1.2
#3 C             0.4          22.8
#4 D             0.2           4  
#5 E             0             0
```

`x %% 1 == 0` returns `TRUE` if the value is an integer (without decimal places).